# How is the direct product of two fields defined?

Tags: field-theory

How does one define the direct product of two fields, and is the direct product of two fields itself a field?

Comment: You can't. There will be zero divisors and the result will not be a field.

Comment: And a field has nothing to do with a [tag:vector-field].

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product

A direct product of two fields is not a field but a ring.